# Question on finite-to-one mapping

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have two slightly different questions.

1. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite-to-one continuous function. For $y\in f(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $n(y)$ be the number of elements in $f^{-1}(y)$.
   Then is either $D_0:=\{y\in f(\mathbb{R}^n):2|n(y)\}$ or $D_1:=\{y\in f(\mathbb{R}^n):2\nmid n(y)\}$ measure zero?
2. Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set. Let $f:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite-to-one continuous function. If $2\nmid n(y)$ holds for any $y$ on the boundary of $K$, then is $D_0:=\{y\in f(K):2|n(y)\}$ measure zero?

_

P.S.  This problem may seem to be a little awkward, because odd or evenness of number of solutions is probably not a very typical property. However, let's consider when $n=1$ and $f$ is a real-coefficient polynomial(just for example). For any $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it can be observed that $\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0^+}n(y)\equiv\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0^-}n(y)  (mod 2)$. Intuitively it says that if you fold a paper then near a folding place there are always even number of sheets.(Seemingly true for general case)

This can be rewritten as "As $y$ moves in $\mathbb{R}$, solutions of $f(x)=y$ move continuously, and sometimes even number of solutions are newly made or deleted, with multipled solution form at making/deleting points." Whether $n$ is odd or even may differ only at making/deleting points, but this set can be shown to be of measure zero.

This is of problem 1, but problem 2 asks a basically similar situation. (Because at boundary of $K$ $f$ should be almost everywhere locally one-to-one, although not very easy to show)

/This is one observation that I had when I first thought of this problem.

Comment: @mdave16 : $bd$ means boundary.

Comment: @mdave16 : Sorry for being late, because of having a work in a haste. The own thought is mostly as posted on question(PS), and adding the reason of making this problem, originally I was to show that a certain function was a homeomorphism, by checking its local change on number of solutions.

Comment: In Q1, can we show that $D_0$ and $D_1$ are measurable sets?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Well, if I said in PS is right, then they should be measurable; since one should be measure zero. However, what you asked can be shown rigorously, as follows:                      let $D$ be the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $f$ is not locally one to one at $x$. Then, $D$ is  measure zero since if we assume $D$ is dense on some open set $U$ then choose any $x_1^1\in U$, then we may choose $x\in U$ near $x_1$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x))=\{x_1^2,x_2^2,...x_p^2\}$, then by moving solution sufficiently small we may make these solutions to be moved to $x_1',...x_p'$ where $x_1'\in D$.

Comment: And then by moving sufficiently small we may move $x_2',...x_p'$ to $x_2'',...x_p''$ and $x_1'$ is again duplicated...since we may do this infinitely many times this contradicts that $f$ is finite to one.

Comment: Now we need two more lemmas; (1)$f(D)$ is closed (2)On any connected component of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus f(D)$ $n$ doesn't change.  ...These are eventually true(by set-point topology). Then $D_0\setminus f^{-1}(f(D))$ should be open thus measurable and $f^{-1}(f(D))$ is measure zero since $f$ is finite to one...thus $D_0$ is measurable and $D_1=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus D_0$ is also measurable.

Comment: -I found this too hard to understand after adding this; but this is just a plot of proof, the full proof I thought is a bit long. but I think I would probably have thought in an inefficient(too hard) way, since I don't know much in this area..

Comment: Anyway, the conclusion is "yes", you may assume $D_0$, $D_1$ are measurable.